# Javascript, Chrome Extension development, close popup

Tags: javascript, tabs, popup, google-chrome-extension

In my manifest i have this:

```
"popup": "1_options.html"
```

and in the above html file I have this code

```
  var saved_email = localStorage['saved_email'];
  if (saved_email !== undefined ||  saved_email != "a@a.com") 
  {
      chrome.tabs.create({url: '0_register.html'});
  }
```

which is working exactly as I want, it opens a new tab with the register.html BUT it still has the popup open on the top right :( `(1_options.html)`

is there anyway to close the popup automatically as I open this new tab?

Thanks!
Ryan

Comment: I'm not putting this down as the answer as I'm not sure, but will `chrome.browserAction.setPopup('')` work? http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html

Comment: It does close for me. Note that it only closes when you do not have the Developer Tools open. Do you have that closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
self.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways to do this, but the easiest is just to call:

```
window.close();
```

You can even do this in a callback function when you create your tab...

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: '0_register.html'}, function() {
  window.close();
});
```

You could also add a listener in your background script to check for tab updates, and if your new tab is your registration window, you could remove the popup:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if(changeInfo.status == "loading") {
      if(tab.url == "chrome-extension://[extension-id]/0_register.html") {
          chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Oops, you wrote in just as I picked the other answer :) Mind telling me how i can close another window (the popup) from the background script? (I already have a tab listener there to capture the address)

Comment: @Ryan The second method is probably the most precise, but at least this should give you plenty of options.

Answer (score 1):

```
      chrome.tabs.create({url: '0_register.html', selected: true});
```

If you don't mind the new tab being selected when it is created, this also forces the popup to close.

Comment: Thanks, will try that as well! (Voted up)